# An 'out-of-the-box' working DAW for music production

Tags: appcenter, audio

I wonder if there is a decent DAW for elementaryOS that can be used straight out of the box. That is to say: With minimal configuration, a beautiful minimalist yet functional professional and engaging interface.

If not, could we build one...?

DAW stands for Digital Audio Workstation. There are several packages for PC,Mac and Linux that can do that job and usually the best ones are only available under commercial license. (Protools, Cakewalk, Samplitude, Reason)

In any case most of them require a certain degree of technical knowledge, proper hardware and spend sometime configuring stuff that in my opinion is never as friendly as it should be. Not to mention a very complex UI.

Linux, however great, also requires huge effort configuring Jack. I've unsuccessfully tried using Ardour, Rosegarden and many other tools available in the App center. Most of them are good but still not quite what I'm looking for.

I believe elementary OS to be the perfect platform to develop a simple yet powerful app capable of recording both audio and midi in a simple way. What I basically need is something that can be installed from the App center and requires minimal configuration. Just plug a mic, usb, analog or midi, and then record.

I'm posting this question because I'd be willing to develop such an app in accordance to elementary's elegant standards. But I would need help and support from fellow programmers as I feel I lack the needed skills to accomplish that.

Any one interested in this idea?

Comment: I feel that this kind of questions are better fit for elementary's reddit page, so I recommend you to ask that question there. Nonetheless, I support this idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [elementary for audio production?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/elementary-for-audio-production)

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with Bitwig, was working nicely on Ubuntu, but I really did not do anything more than just setup and played few samples. I hear nice words about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the few that are available for Linux, and, meh.

That, and sound under Linux can be a pain. Pulse Audio was buggy at times, and JACK made me want to kill myself.

While I use eOS as my primary driver, I dual-boot into Windows and run PreSonus Studio One for my DAW. (That, and soo many VSTs only work under Windows / OSX...)

(Side-story: I reached out to the developers at PreSonus to see if they were working on a Linux version. In short: Nope. The audio-layer is too difficult where OSX and Windows take care of a lot of that for you.)

Answer (score 0):

I would love to work on music in Linux. I will NEVER use Windows again, Mac was fine but OS becomes obsolete.
Linux would be great if the audio interface and routing were simpler. JACK is an utter nightmare for people switching over. Ardour and Reaper are excellent DAW's, that's not the issue, the issue is trying to get the audio running with no hassle. I want to plug in my interface and hit record. ASIO is the best for audio from my experience. If you can make an app that gets rid of JACK...you'd be a hero! Thanks!!!! Love Elementary so far. I'll never go back.